# How to unit tests Type objects in Rails Graphql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I have a rails graphQL API.
I'm struggling to find documentation on how to unit tests my custom Type objects without the need of a query.

For example, I have this type:

```rb
module Types
  class ScheduleType < ApplicationRecordType
    field :size, Integer, null: true
    field :default_fee_cents, Integer, null: true
    field :instructor_name, String, null: true
    field :confirmed_registrations_count, Integer, null: false
    field :program, ProgramType, null: false
    field :teacher, CurrentUserType, null: false
    field :events, [EventType], null: true
    field :registrations, [RegistrationType], null: true
    field :fee_structure, FeeStructureType, null: true
    field :available_spots, Integer, null: true
    field :status, String, null: true
    field :can_edit, Boolean, null: true

    # .. more stuff

    def can_edit
      !object.contains_registrations? 
    end

    def program
      Loaders::RecordLoader.for(Program).load(object.program_id)
    end

    def registrations
      authorize! object, to: :manage?

      Loaders::AssociationLoader.for(Schedule, :registrations).load(object)
    end

    def available_spots
      return if object.size.nil?

      [
        object.size - object.confirmed_registrations_count,
        0
      ].max
    end
  end
end
```

NOTE:
`ApplicationRecordType < BaseObject`
`BaseObject < GraphQL::Schema::Object`

I want to test these methods in isolation. It's hard for me to believe I'd need to use a query to test this. It's like saying I need a controller test in order to unit test my model's method. But I have not found examples, gems or documentation on how to do this so I'm starting to think it's either not a good idea or I'm missing something.